# How to run a function every 3 seconds in Play scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

Iam new to play scala, My use case is run a function every 3 seconds and (Every 3 seconds i check MySQL DB, i get a particular value means proceed to next step). any other possibilities to do...

Answer (score 3):

You should inject Akka `ActorSystem` in your class and schedule a job with it, like:

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
// ...
system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10.milliseconds) {
  file.delete()
}
```

This code is taken from the Play [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaAkka#scheduling-asynchronous-tasks), you should read them. For more complicated tasks use Actors, of course.

Comment: If you're already injecting the `ActorSystem` you may as well inject the ExecutionContext.